# WCF configuration/authentication not working in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, wcf

I'm trying to call an external service that has Windows authentication, it works fine from my Windows development machine running in IIS but once I publish the site to Azure it can't authenticate with the service even if the configuration is the same. The error I get back is,

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException:
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'.
The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'. --->
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

It feels like in Azure it's not even trying the authenticate.

The configuration for the service looks like this,

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="Custom_Binding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://www.otherdomain.com/webServiceRequest" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Custom_Binding" contract="webServiceRequest_Port" name="webServiceRequest_Port" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is the c# code that makes the request,

```
var client = new webServiceRequest_PortClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "domain\Username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
var response = await client.PerformServiceAsync(method, request);
```

/Viktor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you set the Windows credentials?

```
var client = new webServiceRequest_PortClient();
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "domain\Username";
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "Password";
var response = await client.PerformServiceAsync(method, request);
```

Comment: Thanks. This was part of the solution, there was also some configuration issues on my side with the password and username. It for some reason worked when I ran ClientCredentials but not with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException:
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'.
The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'. --->
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized
```

According to exception I assume that you publish your website to Azure WebApp.

If we want to use the Windows Authenticated, we need to ensure that Windows Authentication is enabled for the web server. We could [remote to Azure website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/) to check that there is no Windows Authenticated under the Authentication option, details please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

If Azure could service is possible, could use the Azure [cloud service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-migrate-publish-web-app-to-cloud-service) as a work around.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say it's a App Service.

Comment: Azure also allows us to remote to WebApp site, details please refer to the [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/).